# Push And Present View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, navigation, swift4

I am using a Navigation Controller as a root View Controller and on starting the app a ViewController VC1 appears which has a button that on pressing (with the help of segue) takes you to VC2 which has a table view and 5 cells, Now I Want to use push instead of Segue or present a modal for going to VC3 from VC2 (on click of cells).

I have used

```
let displayVC : ForWebViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ForWebViewController") as! ForWebViewController


self.navigationController?.pushViewController(displayVC, animated: false)
```

The code has been placed under the action of 1st cell's click but nothing happens.
Can anyone help

Comment: VC3 has no any UINavigation controller so first, add UINavigationController before VC3 then try to push view controller in this Navigation stack.

Comment: Try putting a break point on the last line of code, maybe it is not executed.

Comment: check your navigationController is not empty like `if self.navigationController  != nil`. It should not be nil

Comment: Arik Segal Thanks but the Line is executing

Comment: Abdulrehman-warraich it is nil what to DO?

Answer (score 0):

Add navigation controller programatically

```
let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: VC2)
```

Answer (score 0):

- make sure you have a navigationController
- make sure the displayVC is properly instantiated

---

```
let displayVC : ForWebViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ForWebViewController") as! ForWebViewController

present(displayVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

or

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(displayVC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

objective C:

```
PulseNavigationController * VC3 =(PulseNavigationController*)navigationcontroller;

[homeNavictrl pushViewController:VC3 animated:YES];
```

swift:

```
let VC3 = NewViewController()

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC3, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and your storyboard ID

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.section, indexPath.row)//It will print index and section
    let hvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Your Storyboard ID") as! ForWebViewController//Here replace your class name
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(hvc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: the thing is VC1 after Navigation Controller is Pushed but the button on VC1 works with the help of Segue to go to VC2 so here the connection breaks and thus  push does not work when we try to go to VC3 from VC2

Comment: I can't understand

Comment: I mean to say that there are in total 3 VC's with one Navigation Controller, Navigation Controller is the initial View Controler and on starting the app VC1 opens so it is directly linked with navigation controller now there is a button on VC1 that takes u to VC2 but button acts with the help of segue not push so the connection(between Navigation Controller and VC2) is no more there. And the main point is we are currently on VC2 after button click and we want to go to VC3 but with the help of Push, How do we do that?

Comment: It's not a matter how many Navigation Controller's you have, but which VC has that Navigation Controller is the matter. You need Navigation Controller to very first VC. That's enough....

Comment: See, is 1st VC has Navigation Controller or not?,  are you able to navigate from VC1 to VC2?(If yes it's ok fine).

Comment: Yes , i am able to navigate from VC1 to VC to but not through push

Comment: I tried it's working for me, VC1 to VC2 I'm using push segue not code, and VC2 to VC3 I'm using pushViewController code(like above my answer). Here is your Table view delegate functions called or not check once. Here I'm using only one navigation controller for first VC.

Answer (score 0):

There might be one of the possible things because of which you are facing the issue. Do check the below points:

**1.** Have you set the `delegate` of `tableView` to `VC2`. You can do it in the `storyboard` itself or in `viewDidLoad()` of `VC2`, write the below code:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
```

**2.** Check if the `navigationController` instance is not `nil` in the below code:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(displayVC, animated: false)
```