# performSegue does not work if VC is not embed in Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I've got the following code:

```
let file = "user.json"
if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

    let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

    do {
        let text = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
               
                                                
        if text != "" {
            let data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: text.data(using: .utf8)!, options: []) as? [String]
                                        
            userData = data!
                                                            
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: nil)
        }
                
    }
    catch {
                
    }
}
```

When my ViewController was not embed in Navigation Controller, `performSegue` did not work, but as I embed it, it started to work. I'm wondering what's the matter.

Thanks

Comment: What is the segue type? is it a push segue? then it makes sense that you need to embed it into NavigationController isnt it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52962558/push-and-present-view-controller Take a look here too. More answers like the one posted by @SandeepBhandari